# Use of bit.ly service returns error in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, bit.ly

I have several valid URLs in a column, A, (they are all URLs to various Google+ community posts) in my Google spreadsheet. I have followed the instructions provided on this page - http://dev.bitly.com/spreadsheets.html. Some URLs are not being converted and I see #N/A in several cells. The error message appears as a note in those cells and reads -

```
Could not fetch url: https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?format=txt&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&longUrl=https://plus.google.com/112120971021329085014/posts/Xrz7ZP231R7
```

where ACCESSTOKEN is my generic access token. These same URLs can be shortened using curl.

What could possibly be wrong that the shortening is failing in the spreadsheet? Any tips/advice much appreciated.

Comment: I noticed two things that some error messages read - Import internal error and that different URLs fail when closing and re-opening the sheet